# Existence of a sequence of elements picked arbitrarly

Tags: axiom-of-choice

How to prove with the axiom of choice that : Given a family of non empty sets $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$, there exists a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ such that for any $n\in\mathbb N$, $x_n \in A_n$.

I don't know how to proceed... fixing $n$ then apply the axiom of choice to $A_n$ ?

Thanks in advance for answers :)

Comment: There are several equivalent ways to state the axiom of choice, and for some this is literally just an instance of the axiom.  So if you want a helpful answer you should probably state exactly what your version of the axiom of choice says.

Comment: My version of the AoC is $\forall X, (X\neq \emptyset \land \emptyset\not\in X) \Rightarrow \exists (f : X \to \bigcup X) : \forall A\in X, f(A)\in A$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice) expresses the axiom of choice as

$$ \forall X \left[ \emptyset\not\in X \implies \exists f:X\to\bigcup X\quad
   \forall A\in X\ (f(A) \in A) \right]. $$

By taking $X:=\{A_n \mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, since each $A_n$ is nonempty, we are given a function $f:X\to\bigcup X$ such that $f(A) \in A$ for every $A \in X$. Now set $x_n:=f(A_n)$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ to obtain the desired sequence.

In fact, this only requires countable choice because in our case $X$ is countable.

Comment: Ok... I see.. thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to apply the axiom of choice in order to choose from *one* $A_n$, or even from finitely many of them.

The axiom of choice is needed when you want to choose from *all* of the $A_n$'s simultaneously. Of course, this cannot be done by repeatedly choosing elements, since a proof is finite, and there are infinitely many $A_n$'s.

However, the axiom of choice states (in one of its formulations) that if there is a family of sets, all of them are non-empty, then there is a function choosing an element from each set. This is literally what you're asking for. However, the axiom of choice has many *many*, ***many***, forms in the literature. So the exact details would depend on your formulation of the axiom.